# Cannot set CommandParameter using ElementName

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a TreeView with ContextMenu, and inside that menu I want to bind to a command on VIewModel

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding View}">

    <TreeView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Remove" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=treeView, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </TreeView.ContextMenu>
</TreeView>
```

I receive an exception in Output window, like

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=treeView'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem; DataItem=null; target element is 'RadMenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')
```

I am actually using RadTreeView, but the same applies for TreeView. Why I cannot bind to TreeView's SelectedItem property? I have tried with RelativeSource AncestorType, the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, like the Popup control, it's a different visual tree. The error is telling you that it is trying to find a property called '`CommandParameter`' on a '`RadMenuItem`', because this is the DataContext it has within the ContextMenu's visual tree.

This will help you: [Placement Target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget.aspx)

I ended up setting the `CommandTarget` property of the MenuItem to the ContextMenu's `PlacementTarget` property, but it doesn't look like that's the approach you're taking.  Even still, the `PlacementTarget` is what you're looking for.